# Riddle- Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word

I am something invaluable.

Hey! If you are a gold medalist, you cannot assess me. But be a silver medalist , I will surrender.

Tom says distance between two places can't be more longer than me.

Are you clueless about what's happening ! I can tell you what's going on if you can wait for a week.

Who am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the answer is:

> Time

I am something invaluable.

> 'Time is precious' (though 'time is money' as well...)

Hey! If you are a gold medalist, you cannot assess me. But be a silver medalist , I will surrender.

> *First* is not a unit of time, but **second** is

Tom says distance between two places can't be more longer than me.

> I'm not sure who Tom is (maybe this is some reference I'm missing) but distance is finite and we measure distance in light years (in some cases)

Are you clueless about what's happening ! I can tell you what's going on if you can wait for a week.

> 'Time will tell' (a week is a length of time)

Comment: I don't know about all females, but my friends and I use Tom as slang for - its that "Time of the Month". So if the answer is time, it might could apply in that way...if Tom has an underlying meaning in the question, that is.

Comment: Tom reference explained here: https://www.quora.com/What-does-this-quote-%E2%80%9CTime-is-the-longest-distance-between-two-places-%E2%80%9D-by-Tennessee-Williams-The-Glass-Menagerie-mean-to-you

Comment: The last clue meant to imply Time weekly news mag.